# How to avoid calling every time a method

Tags: javascript, optimization, requirejs, logic

I have method like below

```
function setme(){
   var date = 'new date()';
}

function getName1(){
 setme();

}

function getName2(){
 setme();

}

function getName3(){
 setme();

}
function getName4(){
 setme();

}
```

how do avoid calling *setme* method every time, do we have any other optimized solution ?

Comment: Why do you need 4 functions that do the exact same thing?

Comment: Just call setme() instead of using 4 functions to call setme()

Comment: no other 4 function does lot more things. but i want to avoid setme in every function ?

Comment: Could create a singleton class for your data

Comment: If you are looking for optimization you also need think about javascript at it's core because it is a very simple language with a lot of syntactic sugar built on top of it.  A method inside an Object is simply a function assigned to the object's property.  Based on that you can use dependency injection in order to define new methods in an already existing object to keep the memory usage low and only inject methods when needed.  We need to know your exact goal to give you the optimal solution unless you are actually just looking to make your code simpler.

Comment: @BryanWelter I wanted my code simpler, but if i need value in all methods i have call that function every time

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to accomplish since a date will always need a function to retrieve the latest. But if what you want is to define variables in the constructor in a class oriented way:

```
    class Names {
            constructor() {
                this.date = new Date();
            }

            getName1() {
                return this.date;
            }

            getName2() {
                return this.date;
            }

            getName3() {
                return this.date;
            }
        }
    //If you only create a new class object
var n = new Names;
console.log(n.getName1());
console.log(n.getName2());
console.log(n.getName3());

//if you create a new class object for every call

        console.log((new Names).getName1());
        console.log((new Names).getName2());
        console.log((new Names).getName3());
```

Comment: If i am using constructor class then i would prefer your solution, but what i don't want  is calling setme function in every method. do we really have any other option or what i am doing it right?

Answer (score 1):

This will only set date once and then set the setFunction to null to release the memory if your setFunction is very large for some reason.

```
function executeOnce(executable) {
  return function () {
    if (executable !== null) {
      executable();
      executable = null;
    }
  }
}

var setme = executeOnce(
  function() {
    date = 'new date()';
  }
);

function getName1(){
 setme();

}

function getName2(){
 setme();

}

function getName3(){
 setme();

}
function getName4(){
 setme();

}
```

Comment: Above code can be still refined, but that's not i am looking for.

Comment: If you can give more background as to why you don't want to call the function multiple times then we can answer your question better.  Your question just needs more definition / constraints, there is not a clear goal.